# Angular 5 - Function returning Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having issues with a function returning Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Here is the code:

```
export class AppComponent {

public data: any;

constructor() {

this.data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        'title': 'Title 1',
          item: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Item Title 1',
            config: {
              row: 1,
              col: 1,
              sizex: 1
            }
          }
      }
    ];

}

}
```

And the function that's retuning the error:

```
  add() {
    this.data.item.push({ title: 'pushed', config: { sizex: 1} });
  }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In your declaration, `item` is an object, not an array, so you can't call push on just any object. Try to add `[` `]` around it.

Comment: There is no `data.item`; `data` is an array, not an object.

Comment: what is error you are getting ?

Comment: Also, please add expected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First, you are trying to push into the first element of an array, since **this.data** is an array, but you are using data.item. You must use data[0].item (or whatever index it is that you want to push to), or else you would have to push in an entirely new object with an id, title, item, etc. (but i don't think that's what you are trying to do). Secondly, **item** itself is not an array, so you cannot push into the item property. You must make that an array in order to push into it. Your end product can look like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

    public data: Array<any>;

    constructor() {

        this.data = [
            {
                id: 1,
                'title': 'Title 1',
                items: [{
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Item Title 1',
                    config: {
                        row: 1,
                        col: 1,
                        sizex: 1
                    }
                }]
            }
        ];

    }

    add() {
        this.data[0].items.push({ id: 2, title: 'pushed', config: { sizex: 1 } });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn this.data.item into an array and then you should be able to push whatever you want:

```
   this.data = [
          {
            id: 1,
            'title': 'Title 1',
              item: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Item Title 1',
                config: {
                  row: 1,
                  col: 1,
                  sizex: 1
                }
              }]
          }
        ];
```

In the add function for this to work, you'll want :

```
 add() {
    this.data[0].item.push({ title: 'pushed', config: { sizex: 1} });
  }
```

Comment: The syntax around your item array is incorrect, you forgot the `{` `}`.

Comment: Still, that won't work because of the way OP accesses data array in his add function.

Comment: I updated for what I think the add method should be for this to work

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat that is not true. You can push objects with different properties into the same array. This jsfiddle proves it: https://jsfiddle.net/48m0nbgy/1/ .

Comment: I removed the comment and won't debate on that as my memory is not fresh enough. I would point out though that JSFiddle uses javascript, and ES6 or not, this is not TypeScript and some things may compile with one and not with the other.

Comment: Angular code is wrote with Typescript, so OP's problem must be able to compile with it which is more strict that simple JS ES5/6. But this is out of topic right now.

Answer (score -2):

try declaring your data as

```
public data : Array<any> = [];
```

so that you can use `push`.

Since item is an object make that an array type.

```
var x = { .....
item:[],
.....
}
x.item.push(something);
```